# Wildfly Resource Servlet

Tags: jboss, wildfly

can anybody tell me how I can extend the default wildfly servlet for resource resolution (for resources like .html, .css,..)?
Which class do I have to extend and how do I have to configure the servlet to replace the original one?

Comment: Why you want replace original? You can write your servlet and use it without replacing original

Comment: Ok, replacing the servlet was my first idea. It´s ok for me to leave the original servlet but what is the Class-name  of this servlet so that I can extend it? And how can I configure it to be used for resource loading?

Comment: Technically, you can also just use native undertow configuration to serve the files http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/9.0.0.CR2/subsystem/undertow/configuration/handler/file/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The 'default' servlet à la Apache Tomcat doesn't serve static resources. You have to use Undertow resource handlers just like John wrote.
http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/index.html